# mobile app want graphical text to change font size per line automatically, like on tiktok/instagram alternating lines different sizes

Tags: react-native, text, fonts, font-size, text-size

On TikTok and Instagram, they can generate automatically text font size like this image, where alternating lines have different font sizes automatically. I'm trying to figure out how to code that in React Native for mobile IOS and Android: [[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8cAL.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkhIo.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XcjLq.jpg)

I couldn't figure it out. I made something that I'm not crazy about, which is just having a larger font on the first three lines and then a smaller font. See image: But I don't like it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRnt3.png)

Comment: If you use [PixelRatio](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio#getfontscale) to get the font sizes absolute size, then you will know the number of characters you can fit per line. Take the text, split int to words, then use the absolute font size and the parent view width to determine when to split the words to new lines. Map over the lines, using whether the index is odd or even to determine whether the font will be normal sized or bigger

Answer (score 0):

I totally misunderstood what `PixelRatio.getFontScale` did. I thought it would provide the average width a single character takes up on screen. If you can find a way to get a rough estimate of the width of a single character, then this method will work [link](https://snack.expo.dev/GN9gtmozAL):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, PixelRatio } from 'react-native';
import rnTextSize from 'react-native-text-size';
import reduce from 'awaity/reduce';
import useViewLayout from './useViewLayout';
const fontScale = PixelRatio.getFontScale();

const showLayoutValues = true

export default function MultiLineText({
  width,
  containerStyle,
  textStyle1 = { fontSize: 16 },
  textStyle2 = { fontSize: 22 },
  str,
  ...textProps
}) {
  // containerLayout will provide the max width each line can have
  const [containerLayout, onContainerLayout] = useViewLayout();

  // lines was created in a useMemo hook but I wasnt sure if
  // useMemo could handle async
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const calcLines = async () => {
      let words = str.split(' ').filter((s) => s.trim().length);
      let newLines = await words.reduce(
        async (prevPromise, curr, index) => {
          const prev = await prevPromise;
          let lineIndex = prev.length - 1;
          let style = index % 2 == 0 ? textStyle1 : textStyle2;
          const fontSize = style.fontSize;
          // I wanted to use this https://github.com/aMarCruz/react-native-text-size/
          // to measure text width but expo doesnt support it
          const config = {
          // if you exported from expo and link rnTextSize set this to true
            useMeasureModule:false,
            fontProps:style
          }
          const useMeasureModule = false;
          let lineWidth = await getTextWidth(
            prev[lineIndex],
            fontSize,
            config
          );
          let wordWidth = await getTextWidth(curr, fontSize, config);
          // if currentLine can fit the next word add it
          if (lineWidth + wordWidth < (width || containerLayout.width))
            prev[lineIndex] += curr + ' ';
          // or put it on the next line
          else {
            prev[lineIndex + 1] = curr + ' ';
          }
          return prev;
        },
        ['']
      );
      setLines(newLines);
    };
    calcLines();
  }, [str, containerLayout, width, textStyle1, textStyle2]);
  return (
    <>
      {showLayoutValues && <Text>Container Layout: {JSON.stringify(containerLayout,null,4)}</Text>}
      <View
        style={[styles.container, containerStyle]}
        onLayout={onContainerLayout}>
        {lines.map((line, i) => (
          <Text
            {...textProps}
            // to ensure that lines dont wrap
            numberOfLines={1}
            style={[textProps.style, i % 2 == 0 ? textStyle1 : textStyle2]}>
            {line}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

const getTextWidth = async (str, fontSize, config={}) => {
  const {fontProps, useMeasureModule} = config;
  if (!useMeasureModule) {
    // random mathing
    return str.length * fontScale * fontSize ** 0.8;
  }
  let measure = await rnTextSize.measure({
    ...fontProps,
    text: str,
  });
  return measure.width;
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});
```

And then in use:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MultiLineText
        containerStyle={{
          width: '100%',
          backgroundColor: '#eef',
          alignSelf: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
        textStyle1={styles.text}
        textStyle2={styles.text2}
        str="I am really not sure as of how long this text needs to be to exceed at least 3 lines. I could copy and paste some stuff here but I think if I just type and type it would be quicker than googling, copying, and pasting"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've read somewhere that W (capitalized) is the character that usually takes the most amount of width and l/i the least. (there are many fonts so there probably are exceptions), so if you were to get the widths of both of these characters  and gave them a weighted average, you could approximate the max words a line could fit pretty nicely

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that [onTextLayout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#ontextlayout) is a thing. It gives about each line in the Text component, including info about the characters present on each line. This could be used to figure out where to break lines of text ([no planned web support](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1685)):

After tying the str prop to a text input it became very clear that it is ideal to prevent this component from re-rendering as much as possible so I made additional changes ([demo](https://snack.expo.dev/RsCOy8ZtK?platform=android))

```js
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect, memo } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

// text lines will alternate between these styles
const defaultLineStyles = [
  { color: 'red', fontSize: 16 },
  { color: 'blue', fontSize: 22 },
  { color: 'green', fontSize: 28 },
];

function MultiLineText({
  containerStyle,
  lineStyles = defaultLineStyles,
  str,
  ...textProps
}) {
  const [lines, setLines] = useState([]);
  // each time a substring is added to line,
  // remove the substring from remainingStr
  const [remainingStr, setRemainingStr] = useState('');
  const onTextLayout = useCallback((e) => {
    // the first line of text will have the proper styling
    let newLine = e.nativeEvent.lines[0].text;
    setLines((prev) => {
      return [...prev, newLine];
    });
    // remove newLine from remainingStr
    setRemainingStr((prev) => prev.replace(newLine, ''));
  }, []);
  // when str changes reset lines, and set remainingStr to str
  useEffect(() => {
    setLines([]);
    setRemainingStr(str);
    
  }, [str]);
  return (
    <>
    <View style={[styles.container, containerStyle]}>
      <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {lines.map((line, i) => (
          <Text
            {...textProps}
            style={[textProps.style, lineStyles[i % lineStyles.length]]}>
            {line}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      {/* this view will be invisible*/}
      {remainingStr.length > 0 && (
        <View style={{ opacity: 0 }}>
          <Text
            {...textProps}
            onTextLayout={onTextLayout}
            style={[
              textProps.style,
              // use lines.length to get proper style
              lineStyles[lines.length % lineStyles.length],
            ]}>
            {remainingStr}
          </Text>
        </View>
      )}
    </View>
    </>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height:'50%'
  },
});
// be careful when passing non memoized array/objects
export default memo(MultiLineText)
```

Its important to note that objects/arrays that arent memoized/state/refs will cause the memoized component to re-render, even if the values are static e.g

```js
<MultiLineText
   containerStyle={{
     width: '100%',
     height: 200,
     backgroundColor: '#eef',
     alignSelf: 'center',
     alignItems: 'center',
  }}
  style={styles.defaultTextStyle}
  str={text}
  lineStyles={[styles.text,styles.text2]}
/>
```

containerStyle and lineStyles are getting new objects and arrays every time its parent component re-render, which will make MultiLineText re-render (even though its memoized). After moving the containerStyle to the stylesheet and memoizing lineStyles re-rendering becomes better:

```js
const lineStyles = React.useMemo(()=>{
    return [styles.text,styles.text2]
  },[])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput onChangeText={setText} label="Enter some text" value={text} />
      <MultiLineText
        containerStyle={styles.textContainer}
        style={styles.defaultTextStyle}
        str={text}
        lineStyles={lineStyles}
      />
    </View>
```